# "You are smarter than you appear" or "....than you appear to be"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I couldn't decide which one is grammatically correct.

"You are smarter than you appear."  Or

"You are smarter than you appear to be."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are possible.
See an example from Merriam-Webster's Dictionary:
APPEAR
: to have an outward aspect :
She appears (to be) happy enough.